# How we can save the newsletter to true for customer on checkout page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer, newsletter

I have created a Js component in which i am showing a checkbox of Register for Newsletter.It is showing above shipping form that is correct.

What i want that when i will check this checkbox then it should be saved to the customer for subscribed to newsletter.

[image]

Comment: have you search any extension ?

Comment: yes but not found any related to this.

Comment: few day ago I need same and I used https://marketplace.magento.com/mageside-module-subscribe-at-checkout.html